# Node.js struggling with using (nodemailer) middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, nodemailer

I have some interesting question. I'm a newbie in Node.js and Express, so I do really need help with it. (I know this is basics, but first I'm struggling with something for some long time, then ask for help.

I'm trying to create simple app with nodemailer lib. Here below code of working example.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let corsOrigins = [];

if (process.env.REQUESR_ORIGIN) {
    corsOrigins = [process.env.REQUESR_ORIGIN];
}
else {
    corsOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000", "*"];
}
const corsOptions = {
    origin: corsOrigins,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'me@gmail.com',
        pass: 'jdwpkdszkmhmuwvnb'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'me@gmail.com',
    to: 'friend@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy Man!'
};

const Mailer = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});

//Middleware

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());//data JSON

app.listen(PORT);
```

but if I make it like external.js file

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'me@gmail.com',
        pass: 'jdwpkdszkmhmuwvnb'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'me@gmail.com',
    to: 'friend@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy Man!'
};

const Mailer = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

And when I try to import it in my app.js in this way: `app.use(Mailer)`, it shows me errors. The question is: How can I provide this middleware. I will be really appreciate for some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Mailer` is not a middleware. Reading through the type definition I found out that the `.sendMail` method with the overload you are using returns nothing therefore `Mailer` having the "value" of undefined. In the first snippet your are not trying to pass `Mailer` into `app.use` which is the reason why there is no error.

Comment: Could you please help me what do I need to add, to make it working?

Comment: I refer to the [documentation for writing middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).